# Any chess software with "force move" facility?

Tags: software

Does anyone know if there is a chess program on the market (PC or iPad) which provides force-move functionality while it is the computer's turn to play (the opponent tells the computer program which move it must make)?
I think that is the best option to practice one's openings serially.

That's different from the "switch side" functionality which, as far as I know, can only be made while it is your turn to play. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds a lot like "analysis mode" which should be available in many software products. Basically the engine proposes you one or several lines without actually performing the move. You then have do manually perform a move for your "computer opponent" (any of the proposed or any other move).

Answer (score 9):

I know Chessmaster does this (see Ubisoft's [list of controls for Chessmaster X](http://ubisoft.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/218549/0/filename/CHES0026_PCS_Mnl2.pdf)), since I've used Chessmaster X.  In certain (i.e. non-competitive) game modes, Ctrl-F will force the computer to move during its turn.  It isn't a free program, but it has a lot of good resources for a beginner which IMO make it worth it.

**Edit**: It looks as if I have misread the question; I believe you actually meant the player can force the computer to make a *certain* move when it is the computer's turn.  As far as I know, you cannot do this without setting up the board to a certain position, then playing from that position.  E.g. you are White: `1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 ...` and you want to make the computer play `2... f6` to practice your advantage against this opening.  In this case, you would set up the board manually (which Chessmaster as well as most other chess programs allow you to do) as `FEN rnbqkbnr/pppp2pp/5p2/4p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 1 2`, and play as White from there  In most programs, including Chessmaster, you can manually move around/add/remove pieces to attain the desired position.

Comment: I think the question is about forcing *a certain move* by the computer, when you only answer forcing it to play *now*. (What I remember from Chessmaster that tells me that, along with your answer not being so clear about it.)

Comment: I see.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 6):

I do this all the time while in analysis mode using SCID and Stockfish.

Answer (score 1):

StockFish / Small fish / Fritz / Chess master GM version all have this functionality .

Answer (score 0):

> the opponent tells the computer program which move it must make

Every GUI / front-end which allows you to switch between playing against the engine (normally the default mode) and "infinite analysis" has this functionality.

All you need to do on your turn before the computer move you want to force is switch on "infinite analysis", make the forced move for the computer or sequence of forced moves and then switch "infinite analysis" off again.

Answer (score 0):

On [Lichess.org's analysis board](https://lichess.org/analysis#3), you can use the "practice with computer" icon to toggle between analysis mode and having the computer respond to moves.
[image]